# Get model with N child items grouped by field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Table looks like this:

```
  id  ...  item_id  likes
  1          1       200
             1       300
             1       400
             1       4
  ...        2       54
             2       31
             3       22
```

How to get 3 or less items for each item_id with most likes? 
So for my example output should looks like this:

```
[
  item_id: 1,
  likes: 200,
],
[
  item_id: 1,
  likes: 300,
],
[
  item_id: 1,
  likes: 400,
],
[
  item_id: 2,
  likes: 54,
],
[
  item_id: 2,
  likes: 31,
],
[
  item_id: 3,
  likes: 22,
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window function `row_number`

```
with n as (
    select 
        id, item_id, likes, row_number() over (partition by item_id) rn
    from tbl
) select 
    item_id, likes 
from n 
where rn < 4;
```

[Test Mysql window functions](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/6278112fcd41ec6736e5ef45f7de30d7/)

```
<?php

$query = "with n as (
    select 
        id, item_id, likes, row_number() over (partition by item_id) rn
    from tbl
) select item_id, likes from n where rn < 4;";

// Select using Laravel
$rows = $db::select($db::raw($query));

var_export($rows);
```

[Laravel DB query](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/f77276e5c0212c91ca2aeca80bb11ad6/php/php81/aa030722b789ea19cd3114e17fd78bbf/)